# Determine all points in the complex plane where this function is differentiable.

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

With the function being:

$$f(z) = \frac{1}{z^2-iz+1} + \sin(\cosh(z))$$

I'm a little unsure of how to even approach this. I'm guessing that when $z^2-iz+1=0$ the function is not differentiable. Also I'm thinking that because sine and cosh are entire functions that part is differentiable on the entire plane. Is my thinking right and if so how would I go about showing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Entire" means differentiable at every point in $\mathbb C$.

The sum rule, the constant multiple rule, the product rule, the quotient rule, and the chain rule are all the same as in calculus with real numbers.  Consequently the first term is differentiable except where it is undefined because its denominator is $0$.  (If the numerator and denominator were both zero, you'd consider whether the discontinuity is removable, but there's no need for that here.)

Quadratic equations are also solved just as with real numbers.  Although the definition of $\sqrt{b^2-4ac}$ presents a small difficulty, the definition of $\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}$ does not.

Comment: what about for the function $f(z) = sin(abs(z)^2)$?
The CR equations specify that the function is not analytic on the entire domain. Where would the function not be defined?

Comment: The function $z\mapsto \sin |z|^2$ is defined everywhere in $\mathbb C$, but differentiable at only one point in $\mathbb C$, namely $z=0$.  My answer above should not be taken to mean that every function from $\mathbb C$ into $\mathbb C$ is differentiable wherever it's defined.  Rather, it means that functions to which one can apply the various "rules" mentioned are differentiable wherever they're defined. ${}\qquad{}$